# Python Sorting Through Nested Dictionaries

Tags: python, api, dictionary, nested, nameerror

I'm working with the Twitch API and I have a large nested dictionary. How do I sift through it?

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sibstlp', headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json'})
```

then:

```
>>> print r.text
#large nested dictionary starting with
#{"stream":{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sibstlp"},
```

interestingly:

```
>>> r.text
# large nested dictionary starting with
#u'{"stream":{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sibstlp"},
```

Does anyone know why r.text is different from print r.text?

How do I work through the dictionaries to get the information out that I'm looking for?
I'm currently trying:

```
>>> r.text[stream]
NameError: name 'stream' is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are trying to access an element in a string, not a dictionary.  `r.text` simply returns the plain text of the request.  To get the proper dictionary from a `requests` object, use `r.json()`.

When you try `r.json()[stream]`, Python thinks that you are looking for the value in the dictionary corresponding to they key located in variable `stream`.  You have no such variable.  What you want is the value corresponding to the key of the literal string 'stream'.  Therefore, `r.json()['stream']` should give you what you the next nested dictionary.  If you want that url, then `r.json()['stream']['_links']['self']` should return it.

See Ashwini's answer for why `print r.text` and `r.text` are different.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I need to go learn about json now :)

Comment: Python's json library is pretty useful: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 1):

`print r.text` returns the `str` version of the object, while `r.text` returns the `repr` version of the object.

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> print x     #equivalent to : print str(x)
foo
>>> print str(x)
foo
>>> x           #equivalent to  : print repr(x)
'foo'
>>> print repr(x)
'foo'
```

Your keys of that dictionary are strings, if you use `r.text[stream]` then python will look for a variable named `stream` and as it is not found it'll raise  `NameError`.

Simply use : `r.text['stream']`

**Demo:**

```
>>> d= {"stream":{"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sibstlp"}}}
>>> d['stream']
{'_links': {'self': 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/sibstlp'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know how to access the data?

Comment: @IdeoREX use `r.text["stream"]`